# Add-in starts zoom-out when window.location changes. Outlook 2016 version 1711 (Build 8730.2175 Click-to-Run)

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Any location change adds several pixels to the frame width, not to the sidebar width. That's why add-in zooms-out.

We face this problem with angular router which uses location.hash to change pages.

Here is a code example that shows the problem.

```
<p id="debug"></p>
<br>
<a href="{link to any.html}">reload</a>
<br>
<a id="cl" onclick="changeLocationHash()">Change location hash</a>

<script type="application/javascript">
    function changeLocationHash() {
        window.location.hash = '' + Math.random();
    }

    setInterval(function () {
        var _height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var _width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

        document.getElementById('debug').innerText = 'frame ' + _width + 'x' + _height;
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Basically as you keep clicking on your emails to read them the add-in font becomes smaller, smaller, and smaller ...

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue. Please have a look at this [post](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/40) for workarounds and updates on the timeline for this fix.